# Oracle SQL - Extracting <> tag values from LONG Type column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, longtext

I have a table with column name "messages" of **LONG TYPE** 
The messages column contains data like

```
<trans><body></body>...</trans>
```

I want to extract information inside the `<body>` tag only and select it. How would I get that information using an SQL query?

Comment: `data like ...` ... you never showed us the data.

Comment: He had HTML tags in it. That's why they weren't showing. I edited it to show the tags and make the question make more sense.

Comment: <transcript><body>hey</body></transcript>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUBSTR() to extract that. Use the INSTR() function to figure out where the body tag starts, add 6 to compensate for the tag length. For the number of characters to go to, use another INSTR() to find the closing body tag, then subtract the open tag length.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(my_column, INSTR(my_column,'<body>') + 6,
    INSTR(my_column,'</body>') - INSTR(my_column,'<body>') - 5) AS body_extracted
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Some <trans></trans> have (null) values in the table , any way to filter the query so , null values are not shown ? thanks

Comment: Use a common table expression to do the same thing as above but with the trans tag. `WITH temp AS (select [transcode] AS trans_extracted) SELECT ... WHERE trans_extracted = ''`

Comment: Look into that for a little while and if you can't figure it out, post another question on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot . appreciate it !